# Is there a need to test getters and setter methods?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I know this looks like a lazy person question. However I just find it redundantly not necessary to test getter methods and setters for some classes.

Is it absolutely important to test everything for purposes of being sure the software has/doesen't have some bugs.

Comment: Related:  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/130925/54997

Comment: This question is better off @ http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Only If they are beans, its unneccessary.

But if you use the beans as an result of an operation, you test the operation and the get-value may must not the same as the set-value.

Hey using reflection is not a big deal! If you realy are lazy (and good programmers are), test your beans using reflection.